# What is the difference with properties declared in header and implementation file

Tags: iphone

i really think Paul's lectures are great.. i just have a question maybe someone could answer if they don't mind.. In lecture 4, when implementing the new api to the CalculatorBrain class, why was the (id)program property declared in the header file (making it a public property), why not declared in the implementation file like the programStack property. Also, are the accessor methods of properties declared in the implementation files (essentially private properties like the programStack) publicly available? I see he calls the self.program 
stack in the instance method "performOperation"). Would really appreciate it if someone would assist. :)

Answer (score 2):

`properties declared in header and implementation file`

In header means it is available to all other classes. These are either protected or public as per your access specifiers (@publilc , @protected)

In implementation file, it becomes hidden to outside world. (These are private, so not inherited)

In Theory :  Your header files should only expose public interfaces for your classes and everything else belongs in the implementation.

Also : implementation-file ivars are not visible to subclasses, which can occasionally be a little bit awkward if you have manually generated setters and getters that you need to subclass.

Comment: But of course, "hidden" does not mean inaccessible.  If the caller can dummy up the prototypes (or simply use dynamic calls) he can access the "hidden" properties.

Comment: @HotLicks : I agree, if you suggest to add some more to this...please